# Libgdx 2d runner player shadow

Tags: libgdx, box2d

Heelo,

I'm working on 2d endless runner game in libgdx using box2d.

My question is what is the easiest way ti implement shadow for the player which is jumping.

Shadow is just a semi transparent circle, but it needs to be animated when player starts to jump it should be shrinking, when landing it should be opposite

Hope you get an idea.

I have bunch of frames for that animation, but I'm not sure what is the best way to implement this.

My first question is how to detect where shadow should show up on Y axis, for example when player is landing on platform.

I thought of using ghost sensor that is below the player body and contact listener.

Or maybe should I ray cast to find platform beneath the player?
But then I cant know the right moment when player is close to the platform. What do you think?

Also how to calculate distance between player and platform body, so I can choose different frame of shadow animation?

Any thoughts on that?

Thanks.

Comment: To calculate the distance between the player and platform you can use a raycast. Check for dermetfan youtube tutorial about raycasting in libgdx and box2d ! :)

Comment: Maybe all of this raycast thing is a bit overhead. I could create high foot sensor, and when it colides with platform when landing start land animation, and when jumping on a click event jump animation. Then I will have to play a little bit with the timing, but it might be mire efficient. What di yiu think?